# Are there any mass primitivist societies (i.e. population over a thousand people) that currently exist?

Tags: ideology, society, primitivism

I know there are small communes and primitivist societies out there, but are there any primitivist societies in the modern world with a population of over one thousand people? Large uncontacted tribes and those with primitive lifestyles if they have an estimated population of over a thousand people count too! Basically, you need a society that currently exists, has over 1000 people, and [uses](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B0080448542046010) technology before what we consider to be the early modern age which started in the 1500s.

Comment: Do you intend to include uncontacted or nearly uncontracted primitive tribes, such as the indigenous Andamanese people and relict pre-modern tribes in the deep Amazon and Khosian tribes in Africa? Or, do are only thinking about anarcho-primitivism movement groups that are intentionally returning to a less civilized society from a modern one? *See* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-primitivism Do groups that intentionally reject some technologies but not others as a part of a larger society, like the Amish, or ultra-Orthodox Jews to a lesser extent, count as part of the primtivist movement?

Comment: @ohwilleke Should have specified earlier, but primitive tribes also count which is why this question is just about primitivism and not just anarcho-primitivism. The idea, to me at least, is that they can reject technology, but I am thinking of those who basically use pre-early modern age tech so the the Amish might not count

Comment: Would the Amish count as "primitivist"?

Comment: What constitutes a (single) society? Particularly with anarcho-primitivists who are unlikely to have an overarching authority and structure defining the society. Is it based on self-identification ("I'm a X"), geography, or something else?

Comment: @StuartF I guess both self identification and geography. Like, you have a functioning 'society' of sorts and everyone kind of agrees they are a part of this particular tribe or group while being a similar geographic area

Comment: FWIW, I can't imagine why majorities would ever want to return to an era where 50% of children die before adulthood, 5-10% of women ultimately die in childbirth, 30% of political leaders die in hand to hand combat with neighbors, where scourges like famine, bubonic plague, small pox, cholera, tuberculosis, leprosy, and mass death from *E. Coli* were common, with no flush toilets, no air conditioning, patchy heating, no printed books, no significant amounts of imported food, no planes, trains or automobiles, no electronics, & no pianos or brass instruments, if they knew there were alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one indigenous group in the Amazon Rainforest of Venezuela, that according to the article  "Bae-ja: ¿Ser joven? entre los Jotï de la Guayana Venezolana" in the academic journal *Cultura y representaciones sociales* in 2016 may have a population of close to 1200 people, known as the Hodï or Jotï. They mostly live a hunter-gatherer nomadic [lifestyle](https://www.scielo.br/j/bgoeldi/a/N7nj7Krp7SJGMfn6SS7M8sr/?lang=en) and are considered to be an uncontacted tribe.

The Yanomami is another uncontacted tribe with primitive living with [approximately](https://pib.socioambiental.org/en/Povo:Yanomami) 35,000 people in hundreds of villages between Venezuela and Brazil. There are about 16,000 of them in southeastern Venezuela according to an estimate from 2009 and about 19,420 of them in northern Brazil according to an estimate in 2011. The villages are made up of extended families with each village varying in size.

There is also the Hi-[Merimã](http://pib.socioambiental.org/en/c/no-brasil-atual/quem-sao/Indios-isolados) with about one thousand people when the population was last checked. They are in Brazil and speak a language of the same name with a traditional tribal religion.

Answer (score 6):

A primivitist society will support a much lower density of population than a modern one for any given stretch of land. Hunter-gather societies with populations in the 1000s did exist historically, for example in what is today [California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_peoples_of_California) but all land that is sufficiently fertile or otherwise attractive is today used by modern society.

The only remaining hunter-gatherer tribes live in areas of very low land fertility and thus have very low population densities. As they only move on foot that means they are small in absolute population. Maybe some tribes deep in the Amazonian rainforest have more than a 1000 population that is in somewhat regular contact with each other but I consider that very unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

[Korowai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korowai_people) (and probably many more) on New Guinea.

Van Enk and de Vries ([1997](https://books.google.com/books?id=DdpZjOF5QYoC&pg=PA5), *The Korowai of Irian Jaya*):

> The first systematic efforts to contact the Korowai started in 1978. After eighteen months of survey trips by helicopter and boat ... After several trips in dugout canoes, the first meeting with the Korowai people took place on October 4, 1978. ...

> The Korowai share with the other Awyu groups the *khakhua* concept ... *Khakhua* is the name for the persons (always males) with an inner urge or disposition to perform lethal cannibalistic witchcraft, that is, eating the vital organs of their victims. The Korowai have an obsessive fear of *khakhua* and have a very harsh punishment of men with that criminal disposition: the 'witch' is executed and eaten, after a trial that often involves torture. Perhaps even stronger than the fear of 'witches' is the fear of being accused of lethal witchcraft ... The consumption of human flesh occurs only in this khakhua context in Awyu cultures and is not connected with the punishment of other crimes like theft or with headhunting.

> The Korowai do not practise headhunting, which was widespread in southern Irian Jaya before pacification

*The Telegraph* ([2010](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/indonesia/7879391/Indonesian-tribe-officially-recognised-as-tree-dwellers.html)):

> The Korowai, or Koroway, from Indonesia's easternmost region of Papua, live in tree houses, speak their own tribal language, and live off forest animals and plants.

> Almost 3,000 members of the nomadic clan, whose people wear only banana leaves, were recorded for the first time in the country's census this year.

> Members of the tribe skilfully climb ladders to their wooden homes often as high as 164ft (50m) from the forest floor where they usually live in a family of up to eight.

> Homes are built at different heights depending on how well they get on with their fellow tribe members.

> The horticultural tribesmen excel at hunting and fishing.

> Until the late 1970s, when anthropologists embarked on a study of the tribe, the Korowai were unaware of the existence of any peoples other than themselves.

> They have engaged in cannalbalism [*sic*] but anthropologists believe that exposure to the outside world has put an end to this practice in recent years. Korowai people mainly eat wild boar, deer, sago and bananas.

> Only a handful of Korowai are thought to be able to read and write. A total of 2,868 of them were interviewed by census workers through missionary translators using sign language.

> Suntono, the head of Indonesia's statistics agency for Papua, said: "It's as if they're still living in the Stone Age. They don't wear any clothes and they live in trees in the jungles.

> "They eat leaves and hunt wild animals for food," he added.

> "Now that we know who they are, their numbers and characteristics, they won't be isolated anymore. We can ensure they get access to education and health care just like any other Indonesian."

*Reuters* ([2010](http://web.archive.org/web/20200209141015/http://in.reuters.com/article/idINIndia-49607120100624)):

> A tribe of hunter gatherers living in trees in the remote forests of Indonesia’s easternmost region of Papua has been discovered officially for the first time by the country’s census, an official said on Thursday.

> The nomadic tribe, called Koroway, numbers about 3,000 people speaking their own language and living off forest animals and plants, census officials found during the country’s 2010 census survey.

Comment: Can you give more details about this tribe in the body of the answer: estimated population, living style, existing or non-existing contacts with neighbouring tribes or wth scientists or with Papuan or Indonesian authorities... ?